# Alinear imagen al texto con css

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando crear una alerta con css y html como se muestra en la imagen:[notificacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQNGe.png)
ya tengo la imagen encima del rectangulo y que el rectangulo comience justo a mitad de la imagen, sin embargo no logro que mi alerta quede igual que la imagen que subi porque el icono no queda alineado al texto, ¿Alguien podria apoyarme?

Mi código en html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="notificiacion">
 <p class="rectangulo">
  Aqui va el texto de mi alerta
 </p>
</div>
```

Mi código en css es:

```
.rectangulo {
 background-color: #fff6d9;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 margin-left: 22px;
}

.notificiacion > img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 33px;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Con este código logro el siguiente resultado:
[resultado_codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSyvH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te mencionaron, la propiedad *vertical-align* no funciona con elemento float, solo funciona con elementos inline. Te comparto un ejemplo de como quedaría tu código para lograr lo que necesitas.

```css
.notificiacion{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff6d9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.notificiacion{
  line-height: 3em;
}

.notificiacion img{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.notificiacion p{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="notificiacion">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="">
  <p>Aqui va el texto de mi alerta</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, lo he logrado de esta forma en base a tu respuesta:

Comment: .notificiacion{
  line-height: 3em;
}

.notificiacion img{
  float: left;
  margin-top: .7%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.notificiacion p{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff6d9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

Comment: Excelente que bien que te haya sido de utilidad :)

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa por que la propiedad `vertical-align` no funciona con elementos que tienen la propiedad `float`, para que esto te funcione debes cambiar `float: left` por `display: inline-block` para ambos elementos ... no entiendo por que usas `position: absolute` junto con `float: left`

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
.rectangulo {
 background-color: #fff6d9;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 margin-left: 22px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.notificiacion > img {
 width: 33px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Hola, utilizo el _absolute_ para que sobreponga la imagen en el texto con background naranja, si le coloco el _display: inline-block_ me los coloca sobre la misma linea pero uno al lado del otro

Comment: Entonces no entendí tu pregunta..

Comment: requiero que la imagen este alinenada al texto pero sobre el **background** del texto, como se visualiza en la primera imagen

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas con tu código un ejemplo completo que se pueda ejecutar en el snippet de SOes, saludos